# Call an asynch function and return the values which is in the array

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is the asynch function which should return an array, but I'm not sure if I put the return on the right position. I want to return each item of the array names `array_download`

```
async function main() {
        i = 1;
const array_download = [] //Array of downloaded blobs

        for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

          console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
          
          const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
          download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
         
          array_download.push(download)
        } 
           return download

      }

//call the function 
await main().catch((err) => {
        console.error('message'); return null
      });
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: shouldn't you return `array_download` instead of `download`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put async in front of the for loop because its already async
`The for await...of statement creates a loop iterating over async iterable objects as well as on sync iterables,`

Also like posted in a comment above you should return `array_download` instead of download.

```
async main() {
    let i = 1;
    const array_download = [] //Array of downloaded blobs

    for(const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {

        console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
        const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);
        
        const downloadBlockBlobResponse = await blockBlobClient.download(0);
        download = await blobToString(await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody)
        
        array_download.push(download)
    } 
    
    return array_download;
}

try {
    const downloads = await main();
} catch (e) {
    console.error('message');
    return null;
}
```